# Change antenna on '16 Mazda CX-5?

Tags: audio, mazda, cx7

I just bought a universal antenna at pepboys, and I would like to remove the antenna and install this new one. I have a 2016 Mazda CX-5 Sport.

I searched the internet, but didn't find anything straightforward.

How does one remove the antenna and install the new one? I'm new at all of this.

This is the antenna:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiousity, which antenna did you get?

Comment: Take the roof trim off to get at the wiring underneath the fin. Then you should be able to see how to do the rest of the job. With any luck the external fin will be bolted on from the inside. If you get unlucky, it will be attached to the roof by adhesive, in which case good luck removing it without damaging the paintwork!

Comment: Thanks. So the fin isn't part of the "antenna"? I always thought that the fin was the actual antenna.

Comment: At its simplest the actual "antenna" is just a piece of wire. That is probably under the fin. The antenna should be connected to the cable that goes to the radio with a plug and socket that is hidden under the roof trim. For a small antenna, rather than 6 inches of rubber-coated wire sticking out of the car roof, it might plug into a small amplifier (which will also have power leads) that is also under the trim close to it.

Comment: In anticipation of further confusion, I think it's worth mentioning that this antenna you're trying to replace is most likely the antenna for satellite radio. For some cars, you will have to remove the headliner to detach and replace the antenna from inside the car. If you do not subscribe to any satellite radio services, there is no point in replacing this antenna. The antenna for your FM/AM radio is the wire pattern on the rear glass (typically the upper portion).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not subscribed to any satellite radio services. I did not know that the am/fm antenna was in the glass.

Comment: Is there any possible way (maybe something electric) where the satellite radio (the fin) can interrupt the AM/FM signal? Mazda told me that it was the fin, but I've always had this feeling that they did not check anything and just assumed it was the fin.